# How to set timeout to threads?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, python-2.7, timeout

I'm using `threading.Thread` to multi-thread my code.
I want to catch `Timeout exception` if at least 1 of the Threads did not finish their work in X seconds.
I found some answers here, describing how to deal with that, but most of them were UNIX compatible, whereas I'm using Windows platform.

Code for example:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def never_stop():
    while True:
        print 'a'
        sleep(5)
        print 'b'
    return

t1 = Thread(target=never_stop)
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=never_stop)
t2.start()
t3 = Thread(target=never_stop)
t3.start()
t1.join(2)
t2.join(2)
t3.join(2)
```

I tried to set timeout in the `join` method but it was useless..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

When the `timeout` argument is present and not `None`, it should be a floating point number specifying a timeout for the operation in seconds (or fractions thereof). As `join()` always returns `None`, you must call `isAlive()` after `join()` to decide whether a timeout happened – if the thread is still alive, the `join()` call timed out.

Comment: So how do you kill the thread if the thread is still alive after the join timeout?

Comment: @HillarySanders In 2023 this still hasn't been solved.

Comment: Setting `daemon=True` in Thread constructor solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Best way is to make the thread to close itself (so it can close open files or children threads, you should never "kill" your thread).
`join` method only waits until the thread terminates, it won't force it to close.
I suggest changing your `never_stop` method to check the time and `return` or `raise` when time passed exceeds the `X` limit:

```
def never_stop():
    time_started = time.time()
    X = 2
    while True:
        if time.time() > time_started + X:
            return  # or raise TimeoutException()
        print 'a' # do whatever you need to do
```

This way your thread will end itself after `X` sec, you can even pass the X as argument when you create the thread:

```
def never_end(X):
    # rest stays the same, except for the X = 2


t1 = threading.Thread(target=never_stop, args=(2,))
```

`args` is a tuple, it's contents will be passed to the `target` function as arguments.